# Issue with plotting shapefiles on an orthographic projection in Basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap, orthographic

I have been trying to plot Exclusive Economic Zone (EEZ) shapefiles on an orthographic projection from the basemap package. However, the shapefile file has EEZs from around the world, and so when I try to plot the shapefiles there are always some that are not visible in the projection at that particular angle. This results in the shapes being smeared out, which is not quite the effect that I am going for. Ultimately I wish to only plot select shapefiles, but then this same issue will likely pop up so for now I'd be happy to solve this more basic case where I try to plot all of them.

Here in the code I try a simple case where I plot the shapefiles with the readshapefile command from basemap. I have also tried plotting the various shapes as polygons (figured that would give me more flexibility in changing the appearances of the individual shapefiles) but then I could not get the polygons to appear on the map in the right spot and I would see similar smearing behavior (so likely the issue has the same or a similar root cause).

I have attached the code from the simple case below. If I run this, I get the projection to appear as a I want, but with the smearing of the shapefiles. The shapefiles can be found at http://www.marineregions.org/downloads.php#unioneezcountry where I use version 2 of Marine and land zones: the union of world country boundaries and EEZ's.

```
#Here is the figure
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(20,12))
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)

#create the map projection
Map=Basemap(projection='ortho',lon_0=0,lat_0=0,resolution='l')
Map.drawcoastlines(zorder=10)
Map.drawcountries(zorder=10)
Map.drawmapboundary()
#Reading in the shapefile and plotting it
Map.readshapefile('~/EEZ_Boundaries/EEZ_land_v2_201410','countries')
```

[Here is a link to the image I get when I run the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpsfM.png)

Comment: Is it OK if you use `projection='cyl'`?

Comment: With the 'cyl' projection this issue doesn't arise, even if I only plot a subset of the total earth's surface. For now I have therefore been using the 'cyl' projection, but preferably I would like to know what the issue is with the 'ortho' projection so that I can use that instead.

Comment: I guess this is one problem with matplotlib-basemap that `Cartopy` is created to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after more time of trying to get this to work, I have pretty much given up with Basemap and made a (long overdue) switch to cartopy. In that case, the problem does solved by Cartopy already, so the code that creates the figure I was trying to get is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cpf
from cartopy.io.shapereader import Reader

#Set the projection
projection=ccrs.Orthographic(central_longitude=0,central_latitude=0)

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(20,12))
axMap=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1,projection=projection)

#resolution of the coastlines
resolution='10m'
axMap.coastlines(resolution=resolution,edgecolor='black',zorder=10)

#Add the shapefiles
shape_feature = cpf.ShapelyFeature(Reader(direc_shp+file_shp).geometries(),
                               ccrs.PlateCarree(), edgecolor='black')
axMap.add_feature(shape_feature,zorder=1)
```